# End file record in calpuff input file detected

Tags: fortran, modeling

I am trying to model a CALPUFF air dispersion model for pesticides. When trzing to execute the model, I get this error:

```
SETUP PHASE
An endfile record was detected in a READ statement (unit= 1).
 Error occurs at or near line 33360 of _readcf_
 Called from or near line 40403 of _setup_
 Called from or near line 1271 of _MAIN__
```

I have checked the input control file several times, but I just don't know what this endfile record could be...

Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system?  Is this an ASCII text file or a binary file?

Comment: What compiler is on use?

`Line 33360 of _readcf_` ... I despair

Comment: Hey @steve! I am using Windows 11, and the input file is ASCII.

Comment: Hey @IanBush ! The compiler is the one that I downloaded with the model, I think it is specifically for the model. Is there a way to share the input file here? It is too long to post it as code in the question ...

Comment: Is the last line of the file terminated with CRLF or LF?  If the EOF is on the last line, then bad things might happen.

Comment: @IanBush there are three ones that were downloaded with the model, I am not sure which one is actually used: gfortran, ifort and if95

Comment: @steve with crlf... I don't exactly know where the eof is ... I don't get any further information that this error message. I don't even know what these line numbers refer to... definitely not my file.

Comment: The posted error message is not from gfortran.   For the CRLF or LF issue, open your text file.  Go to the last line.  Place cursor at the end of the line.  Hit enter.  Save file.  Try running the code.

Comment: @steve Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately it didn't chance anything...I still get the same error message

Comment: At this point, you will need to determine how unit 1 is opened and likely need to insert a print statement in the code to spit the input file to output.  Either you have a short record or hidden embedded control characters in your file.

Comment: @steve how do EOF records in Fortran look alike? Do you happen to know where I can find information on that? Unfortunately I dont directly see the code, I am just adjusting the model variables, and dont have access to the actual fortran code ...

Comment: In that case we can't help you much, you will almost certainly be better asking in a forum dedicated to the application

Comment: The "end file record" is more than likely just the end of the file.  To say more we need to see code, input and compiler.

Comment: As @IanH says, "endfile record" is just the end of the file. In the days of magnetic tape, there was a physical representation recorded for the end of a file, and that concept remains in Fortran today. There are some compilers that will treat a single byte CTRL-Z as an endfile record, but I agree with Ian that your program almost certainly just read past the end of the data. I'll comment that if the input file isn't where the program expects, it may create an empty one and then get an endfile condition on the first read.